# Set and get block arguments programatically

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

In layout when I create a block I can set custom arguments, for example:

```
<block class="Company\Module\Block\Hello" name="block_name" template="test.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="my_arg" xsi:type="string">testvalue</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

I can later retrieve the argument like this inside the block:

```
$arg = $this->getMyArg();
```

When I create a block programatically (according to this method: [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php#L739)) I can set custom arguments like this:

```
$block = $this->frameworkViewLayout
    ->createBlock(
        "Company\Module\Block\Hello",
        "block_name",
        ['my_arg' => 'testvalue']
    )
    ->setData('area', 'frontend')
    ->setTemplate($template)
    ->toHtml();
```

The block is correctly created and it works perfectly. But I'm not sure how I can later retrieve the argument **inside block's class**. I tried to do it like this:

```
$arg = $this->getMyArg();
```

or

```
$arg = $this->getData('my_arg');
```

But it returns nothing. What did I miss?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you look further in the code, in the `\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block` class, the `createBlock` function only adds data from the `$arguements['data']` element.  So, I think you should change your code to this:

```
$block = $this->frameworkViewLayout
    ->createBlock(
        "Company\Module\Block\Hello",
        "block_name",
        [
            'data' => [
                'my_arg' => 'testvalue'
            ]
        ]
    )
    ->setData('area', 'frontend')
    ->setTemplate($template)
    ->toHtml();
```

Then you could use `getMyArg()` or `getData('my_arg')`.

Comment: What if arguments in array
How to convert if argument is in array like
    <block class="Company\Module\Block\Hello" name="block_name" template="test.phtml"><arguments> <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array"> <item name="components" xsi:type="array"> <item name="msp-recaptcha" xsi:type="array"><item name="component" xsi:type="string">MSP_ReCaptcha/js/reCaptcha</item>
           <item name="zone" xsi:type="string">create</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
        </arguments>

Comment: I have used your code but I am getting only body part not header and footer call

Answer (score 4):

**You can assign directly any variable like,**

```
$block = $this->_layout
    ->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')
    ->setTemplate('Company_Namespace::index.phtml')
    ->setResponse('response')
    ->toHtml();
return $block;
```

and to get variable value in temlate file,

```
echo $block->getResponse();
```

Answer (score 1):

note when sending 'data' array with arguments like mentioned by Jackie here:

```
$block = $this->frameworkViewLayout
->createBlock(
    "Company\Module\Block\Hello",
    "block_name",
    [
        'data' => [
            'my_arg' => 'testvalue'
        ]
    ]
)
->setData('area', 'frontend')
->setTemplate($template)
->toHtml();
```

avoid injecting $data variable in block definition (__construct method)

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand what you mean. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to Magento 2, but try using `$my_arg` or `$block->getMyArg()`.

You should avoid using `$this`, you should use `$block`.

Calling `$this` will activate a proxy method to `$block` class, but I've had problems with magic methods like getters.

Comment: I'm using it inside block class (`Company\Module\Block\Hello.php`) so I need to use `$this`. Variable `$block` doesn't exist there so if I try to use it I will get error `Notice: Undefined variable: block`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I understood you were using in a template file.

Comment: Did you try using $my_arg as parameter in you constructor and checking it?

Comment: @zitix How does that possible, in your xml it clearly says ```template="test.phtml"```. So you are using it in the template, correct me if I am wrong